# How to see the output of Logger in dartlang (Dartium or command-line)

Tags: logging, dart

I'd like to be able to log for debugging purpose from a package that could be either part of a web app or a command line application

Current I use

```
print('some text');
```

But I cannot control at runtime what is printed (DEBUG, INFO, ...)
While I'm used to use java.util.logging.Logger in java, I could not find a way to use the Logger class in the logging package of dart, in either a web or command line application.

```
Logger logger = new Logger('test');
logger.info('some text');
```

The simple code above compiles fine but I cannot see any ouput in either the console of Dartium or the Output pane in the DartEditor.

Has anyone successfully used it (and see some text)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my Dart Bat-belt, I keep a function like this:

```
void printLogRecord(LogRecord r) {
  print("${r.loggerName} ${r.level} ${r.message}");
}
```

Then I'll add it to a Logger, typically the root logger:

```
Logger.root.level = Level.FINE;
Logger.root.onRecord.listen(printLogRecord);
```

Comment: Looks like we should update Logger to use streams. I opened http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=8508

Comment: Thanks for this! Just thought I'd point out that if you do print("${r}"); the toString method will automatically include level, loggerName, and message.

Answer (score 1):

With the lastes m4 release this is the API that worked for me:

```
Logger.root.level = Level.FINEST;
Logger.root.onRecord.listen((LogRecord r) {
  window.console.log('${r.loggerName}(${r.level}): ${r.message}');
});
```